# If it possible to define a "function" such that the normal form will have the arguments in order?

Tags: function-construction, core-language, term-rewriting

[image]

I'm looking for something that acts like this.

How could ord be defined for 2 arguments? What about n?

Since Mathematica is a term-rewriting system it should be possible, but all my attempts were just infinite loops. I have no ideea what part of the language I should be studying for this.

Comment: Try `SetAttributes[ord, Orderless]` (for documentation see [Orderless](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Orderless.html)). Now the arguments should automatically be sorted into canonical order regardless of input order.

Comment: What about a more general normal forms? For example what if I want a function f[a_] that does something only whenever a certain condition applies to a, else it just returns f[a]? I know patterns handle some of this stuff, but is a general normal form possible: "if the argument matches condition do something else do nothing."

Comment: In that case you can use the [Condition](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html) operator `/;` to let your definition only fire under the correct circumstances. E.g.:
`f[a_] := dosomething[a] /; booleanproperty[a]`

Comment: I was hoping I could do that, but somehow f[a_, b_] := f [b, a] /; a > b still doesn't work right (goes into infinite loops). Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: You have the right idea, that code should work. Check your current definition of `f` by evaluating `?f`. If you have old definitions you don't want anymore, either use `Clear[f]` or restart the kernel to get a fresh state with no definitions for `f`. Your code example works fine here for inputs `f[a,b]`, `f[b,a]`, `f[1,5]`, `f[5,1]`.

Comment: Thank you. It works.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad it works now :)